# How to continue a loop after catching exception in try ... except

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, try-except

I am reading a big file in chunks and I am doing some operations on each of the chunks. While reading one of get them I had the following message error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 26 fields in line 15929977, saw 118

which means that one of my file lines doesn't follow the same format as the others. What I thought I could do was to just omit this chunk but I couldn't get a way to do it. I tried to do a `try/except` block as follows:

```
data = pd.read_table('ny_data_file.txt', sep=',', 
                      header=0, encoding = 'latin1', chunksize = 5000)
try: 
    for chunk in data:
           # operations
except pandas.errors.ParseError:
           # Here is my problem
```

What I have written here is my problem is that if the chunk is not well parsed, **my code will automatically go to the exception not even entering the for loop**, but what I would like is to skip this chunk and move forward to the next one, on which I would like to perform the operations inside the loop.

I have checked on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything similar where the try was performed on the for loop. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to do as suggested in the comments:

```
try:
    for chunk in data:
        #operations
except pandas.errors.ParserError:
        # continue/pass/handle error
```

But still is not cathching the exception because as said the exception is created when getting the chyunk out of my data not when doing operations with it.

Comment: What happens if you skip the exception handling and pass `error_bad_lines=True` - does that salvage enough rows to be useful? As you've got `sep=','` - are you sure you shouldn't be using `pd.read_csv` here instead in case the issue is that you're got embedded quotes in columns?

Comment: I do have embedded quotes in columns. ``error_bad_lines = True`` should go as an argument of ``pd.read_csv``?

Comment: Sorry I meant embedded commas in quoted columns but yes - might be worth giving it a go and see if it helps.

Comment: It still gives panda.erros.ParserError

Comment: Sorry use False - not True...

Comment: It worked, could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As suggested by @JonClements what solved my problem was to use `error_bad_lines=False` in the `pd.read_csv` so it just skipped that lines causing trouble and let me execute the rest of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The way you use `try - except` makes it skip the entire for loop if an exception is caught in it. If you want to only skip one iteration you need to write the try-except inside the loop like so:

```
for chunk in data:
    try:
       # operations
    except pandas.errors.ParseError as e:
        # inform the user of the error
        print("Error encountered while parsing chunk {}".format(chunk))
        print(e)
```

Comment: The problem is that I am getting the exception **in** the loop, not inside it.

Comment: Oh like `for chunk in data` itself is the faulty line? Not the content of `# operations`?

Answer (score 1):

I understood that, in the operations part you get exception. If it is like that: you should just continue:

```
for chunk in data:
    try:
       # operations
    except pandas.errors.ParseError:
       # continue
```

Comment: I ma having the exception while reading the chunk. If I try to debug my code after the for loop the code is not even entering there, as the problem is in the for loop, not in the operations done.

Comment: @Marisa: If an error happened getting chunks, you can't continue looping onto the next one.

Comment: Not even with the next chunk? Just omiting that one?

Comment: @Marisa: How could it do that if there was some error?

Comment: Because there would be an error with chunk i-th but not with chunk (i+1)-th.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where the exception is thrown. Maybe adding a full error stack would help. If the error is thrown by the read_table() call maybe you could try this:

```
try: 
    data = pd.read_table('ny_data_file.txt', sep=',', 
                      header=0, encoding = 'latin1', chunksize = 5000)

except pandas.errors.ParseError:
           pass
for chunk in data:
           # operations
```